# Selecting multiple dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data  `table`  as follows:

```
 id    date1      date2        rate
 1     01/01/2017 03/01/2017   0.60
 1     02/01/2017 03/01/2017   0.40
 1     03/01/2017 03/01/2017   0.00
 1     04/01/2017 03/01/2017   0.00
 1     05/01/2017 03/01/2017   0.00
 2         .          .          .
```

For each id, I want to select the most recent positive value for  `rate`  before it goes to 0. So since  `date2` 's value is  `03/01/3017` , the value of id 1's rate goes to 0 on  `03/01/3017` . I want to choose the row where the rate is  `0.40` .

I would want to do this for multiple ids. Also  `date2`  can't be a weekend.

Comment: Please tag your DMBS

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And what do the two dates have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are asking for:

```
SELECT    a.*
FROM      data_table a
          INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
         , MIN(date1) AS date1
    FROM   data_table
    WHERE  rate > 0
    GROUP BY id
) b ON a.id = b.id
       AND a.date1 = b.date1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach. I give the table name as `table1`.

```
SELECT a.id, a.rate
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.date1 = (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM table1 WHERE a.id = id and rate <> 0)
```

`table1` includes the data you provide and 2 lines of data with `id = 2` which are made up by me.

**DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT, date1 DATE, date2 DATE, rate FLOAT);
INSERT table1(id, date1, date2, rate) VALUES
(1,'2017-01-01','2017-03-01',0.60),
(1,'2017-02-01','2017-03-01',0.40),
(1,'2017-03-01','2017-03-01',0.00),
(1,'2017-04-01','2017-03-01',0.00),
(1,'2017-05-01','2017-03-01',0.00),
(2,'2017-06-01','2017-03-01',0.30),
(2,'2017-07-01','2017-03-01',0.00);
```

**RESULT**

```
id  rate
1   0.4
2   0.3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c7250/7)